# How can I make this recurrent equation non-recurrent?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrent equation that defines a sequence $a_k$ from a sequence $b_k$:

$$a_k = b_k - \sum^\infty_{i=k+1}a_i$$

How can I write this equation without mentioning $a_k$ on the right side?

Comment: The given equation easily defines $b_k$ in terms of a summation over terms $a_i$ from $i=k$ to infinity.  Are you trying to "solve" this relationship to obtain $a_k$ in terms of $b_i$'s?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I just saw myself how trivial this question is.

Comment: @FUZxxl: you'd better rephrase your question: there is no $a_k$ on the RHS ! (Just a few $a_i$'s, but no $a_k$ of any kind).

Comment: Obviously, the $b_k$ are the "integral" of the $a_k$, so that the $a_k$ are the "derivative" of the $b_k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$b_k = a_k + \sum_{i=k+1}a_i = \sum_{i=k}a_i$$

$$b_{k-1} - b_k = \sum_{i=k-1}a_i - \sum_{i=k}a_i = a_{k-1}$$